# how to import .gdb having domain which is developed in arcgis into postgresql?

Tags: postgresql

we have geodatabase having domain information and coded value is incorporated in ArcGIS .
the geodatabase having more than ninety lacs record. how can import PostgreSQL

we have geodatabase having domain information and coded value is incorporated in ArcGIS .
the geodatabase having fore than ninety lacs record. how can import PostgreSQL .can domain information is import in PostgreSQL or not
For example, a column design quality could belong to the general domain quality. Quality could then be coded as '1=low, 2=medium, 3=high'. This is to enforce that only certain values are used, for instance in a survey. Ogr2ogr reads the values 1, 2, and 3, but not the accompanying text.

Would anybody know how to include these domains in the transfer from gdb to Postgres / PostGIS?

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to import your data using basic, built-in, unconstrained types, then reflect the same rules in PostgreSQL using [enums](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createtype.html#SQL-CREATETYPE-ENUM), [check constraints](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-constraints.html#DDL-CONSTRAINTS-CHECK-CONSTRAINTS) and [domains](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createdomain.html).

You can aid the process by using ogr2ogr [`-resolveDomains` option](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html#cmdoption-ogr2ogr-resolveDomains) to transfer the accompanying text into an additional column.